# Child Pages Short Code plug-in and hover capabilities?

Tags: plugins, themes, css

Recently was trying to work on Wordpress site that was passed on to me, and it has a page that uses [this plug-in](https://wpist.me/wp/child-pages-shortcode/) and [this one](https://mg.wordpress.org/plugins/children-pages/). The former provides an excerpt of the child-page for viewing purposes on the parent page. 
[image]

So on the WordPress page editor, in Text, there is this code there:

```
[child_pages width="25%"]
```

Would it be possible to add a hover capability to those blocks, where if you hover over one of them, there would be an overlay that then turns visible, with text on it? (to provide more information about the block)
And how would I do it? CSS? how would I access the CSS-- would it be the theme's CSS, or the plug-in's?

Comment: If you are wanting to use CSS to display and hide text that is already in the content of the shortcode - for example, the title or excerpt - yes, that would be possible. Usually people place this type of code in a child theme or a custom plugin. You don't want to edit the plugin or theme directly as your CSS would get lost every time you updated the plugin or theme. However, if you are asking to *add* text that isn't already present in the shortcode, the only option would be to fork the plugin - copy it, rename it, and make your changes.